# How can I create a virtual directory in IIS 5.1, 6.0, 7.0 and 7.5 using a script from with an NSIS install script?

Tags: iis, nsis

I'm trying to install a web application and virtual directory on several versions of Windows OS and IIS (IIS versions 5.1, 6.0, 7.0 and 7.5).  It seems there are different scripts (mkwebdir.vbs, AppCmd) for different versions of Windows.

Presently, I do the following to create a virtual directory for IIS 5.1 (Windows XP):

```
ExecWait "Cscript c:\InetPub\AdminScripts\mkwebdir.vbs -c localhost -w $\"Default Web Site$\" -v myApp,$INSTDIR"
```

I do the following for IIS 7.0 and above:

```
ExecWait "c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\AppCmd add app /site.name:$\"Default Web Site$\" /path:/myApp /physicalPath:$INSTDIR"
```

Are these the best commands for the respective versions of IIS, and what command should I use for IIS 6.0?  Is there a command for creating virtual directories I can use for all versions of IIS I listed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interface to IIS via the [NsisIIS plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsisIIS_plug-in).

The virtual directory creation from NSIS is as simple as

```
NsisIIS::CreateVDir "VDir Name" "Physical Path"
```